# Mongodb is not running or connecting

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't connect to mongodb with a simple code. I've tried it on Linux and Windows 10, but on both operating systems the answer is the same: 
`Failed to connect to server [localhost: 27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]`

On both systems I executed the following commands successfully:
`npm install mongodb --save` and 
`npm install mongoose --save`

I also tried globally:
`npm install -g mongodb` and 
`npm install -g mongoose`

The `mongo` and `mongod` commands are not recognized or are not found when I run them on the command line.

This is my script `test.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
var MongoDB = mongoose.connect(mongoURI).connection;
MongoDB.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err.message); });
MongoDB.once('open', function() {
  console.log("mongodb connection open");
});
```

How do I check for certain that mongodb is running on both systems?
How to correct this error that is occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `npm install mongodb` that does **not** install the MongoDB server. That only installs the MongoDB Node.JS Driver. You need to download and install MongoDB server separately for you platform, head over to https://www.mongodb.com/download-center for that.

Comment: Thanks @helmy. But I just need to connect via Node.js. Is it necessary to install MongoDB as well?

Comment: Connect to what? MongoDB is a database, which has to be installed and run as a separate process, and that's what your Node.js application will connect to. The reason your Node.js code is saying that it can't connect is because the database is not running and it has nothing to connect to!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie, and I've been trying to figure out how to use Nodejs and Mongodb. I'm seeing some tutorials that show just what I'm pointing out in my initial question, where those who use MongoDB just install it the way I said and I did as well. I agree with you that it is necessary to have the script and database connected, but I assumed it would be like in SQLite, in which, after installing using "npm install" and executing the script, then the data file would be created immediatly if not existed.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. I think that many of the tutorials might make certain assumptions like these that are easy to overlook. This quickstart might be helpful if you haven't seen it already: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/quick-start/quick-start/

Comment: Thank you Helmy! But now a saw what you pointed out, so I really have a problem. There is no version of MongoDB for Windows10 32bits available for download. There is also no version of MongoDB for Linux 32bits (Debian in my case). I'm trying to solve an automation problem that uses 32bit equipment only. I think I'm going to have to change databases...

Comment: If you go to previous releases (https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#previous) you can access 32-bit windows builds (i386) of version 3.2 and there are also generic linux 32-bit "legacy" builds.

Comment: Hi @helmy, very nice! It works on Windows. I downloaded the previous version of Mongodb as you pointed out: `Mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.12-signed.msi`. After install, I suffered a lot to make the MongoDB service work. I discovered that I had to run the command `mongod --storageEngine = mmapv1 --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db` (I chose a different default path, `c:\MongoDB\Data\db`). So, after Windows reboot, It was possible to start / stop the Mongodb service only with `net start MongoDB` or `net stop MongoDB`. On Linux I have not tested it yet. For now it's enough for my tests. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad you got it working @wBB. If you wouldn't mind, please mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See:
[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Install NPM dependencies:-

1.mongodb-uri

2.mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uriUtil = require('mongodb-uri');
var connect = function() {
        mongoose.connect(uriUtil.formatMongoose(dbConfig.host));
    };
    connect();
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.log);
    db.on('disconnected', connect);
```

thank you

Comment: Hi @hardy, it does not work like it used to.
I ran `npm install mongodb-uri --save`, but when running your sample code, the error remains as shown below. Thank you anyway.

`MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1
27017]`

Comment: are you inserting correctly your host (as `string`) in this line,Insted of dbConfig.host .                               `mongoose.connect(uriUtil.formatMongoose(dbConfig.host)); `

Comment: Yes, I changed that string:
`mongoose.connect(uriUtil.formatMongoose("mongodb://localhost:27017/test"));`

Comment: if you are connecting to your localhost then you have run mongod.exe   
 (for windows) file , to make your database listen at 27017. Otherwise its working fine here.

Comment: I'm trying to run on Windows and Debian 8. On Windows I am not finding the mongod.exe file. On Linux I do not know what to look for. And I have one more problem in Windows if I have to install MogoDB: I use Windows 10, so mongodb.org has no installer for this version of Windows.

Comment: Hi @hardy. On Windows I have already solved the problem as indicated by helmy. Thank you very much for your attention.